# centered max-width doesn't fluid with display:flex

Tags: css, flexbox, fluid

To center items with `display: block` people use `margins: auto`. If I set `max-width` to child that needs to be centered and there's enough space around it will fluid as much to `max-width` as it needs to (depending on its content). But if I change `display` property of parent element to `flex` it doesn't take all free space anymore. I really need to use `max-width` since I want element to shrink on small screens.

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7ymrk0v/1) . Clicking on the button swaps `display: flex` to `display: block` on parent. I want the green space on `flex` to fluid as much as it's possible for `max-width` as it's done with `display:block`

**EDIT**:
I also would like to use `flex-direction: column`

```js
$('input').click(function() {
  var curDisplay = $('#parent').css('display');
  if (curDisplay == 'block') {
    $('#parent').css('display', 'flex');
    $('input').val('flex');
  } else {
    $('#parent').css('display', 'block');
    $('input').val('block');
  }
})
```

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}
#child {
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
input {
  width: 100%:
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <input type="button" value="Click Me!" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for flex-basis. By using a % you can get very close. You can use px to set the initial width, it will still be "responsive" until you hit the minimum width if you have it set.

on the child element:

```
div {
    flex-basis:40%;
}
```

Here is the [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-basis.asp)

Comment: Oh, I already tried it, forgot to mention I use `flex-direction: column`. It doesn't work along with it. Here's https://jsfiddle.net/f7ymrk0v/1/

Comment: flex-direction:row; is not an option?

Comment: Unfortunately no, Is there an alternative way for `max-width`? I just need  fixed width div that's able to shrink if parent narrows.

Comment: how about % width on the child, then override it later when you add more child elements?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the width of the child to 100%? If you need to center the button in the child you can simply add:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Also remove `width: 100%` from the input.